# HTML Email putting slices together

Tags: html, email

I am trying to do the following design
[image: design]

So my outer table will have 2 table rows.

The first table row will have 3 td's which will each contain their own inner table (tables represented by colour shading in the design).

So my first table rows tds look like this

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" width="186" height="20"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="image4.jpg" alt="" width="34" height="66"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image5.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="66"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image6.jpg" alt="" width="32" height="66"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><img src="image12.jpg" alt="" width="186" height="20"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" width="67" height="106"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="" width="397" height="26"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="image7.jpg" alt="" width="178" height="25"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image8.jpg" alt="" width="83" height="25"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image9.jpg" alt="" width="15" height="25"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image10.jpg" alt="" width="121" height="25"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><img src="image11.jpg" alt="" width="397" height="55"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now everything looks fine, just how it should do.  I am not too sure if I have done the colspans correctly though?

Anyways, moving onto the second table row, I have the following

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
       //first table row data
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="image13.jpg" alt="" width="33" height="122"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                    <td><img src="image14.jpg" alt="" width="255" height="122"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="image15.jpg" alt="" width="362" height="122"  border="0" style="display: block;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As soon as I add the second row, my design messes up.  Essentially, I end up with my design looking something like the following
[image: design2]

How can I avoid this from happening?  I think it may be to do with my colspans, not too sure though.

Thanks

Comment: Regardless, this will look really bad on a pocket PC (phone)

Answer (score 1):

*A couple huge things..*

Where is this appearing? Outlook I presume, what version(s)?

define inline `widths` and `max-width` for each element where width is a concern, do it inline within table HTML. Maintain outer table wrapping all elements within. If main outer table element is ignored. Nest a few tables as wrappers until elements are contained to desired layout. Use CSS but do it inline.

Read this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/).

Comment: I am not actually even testing it in an email client at the moment, just viewing it directly within firefox.

Comment: I have tried following all the guidlines, still getting the strange gaps.

Comment: There are case by case quirks. You have to figure out your support zone. And once you do that you have to debug and test there. I just passed you a free email testing tool. G'luck!